# OpcUA address space

Tags: qt, opc-ua, qt6

I'm working the first time on a project that requires an OpcUA connection.
I'm using the Qt wrapper (Qt OPCUA) with the `open62541` backend.

The manufacturer of the PLC that hosts the server told me the list of the variables I can access:

```
MT_MAX_SETUP (qreal)
MT_ALARM (bool)
...
```

and several others.
Using the [example](https://doc.qt.io/QtOPCUA/qtopcua-opcuaviewer-example.html) `Qt OPC UA Viewer Example` I discovered the `nodeId` of those variables, for example:

```
`ns=4;s=MT_MAX_SETUP`
```

so I can retrieve its value after connection in this way:

```
_opcNode = _opcUaClient->node("ns=4;s=MT_MAX_SETUP");
connect(_opcNode, &QOpcUaNode::attributeRead, this, &MyOPC::handleAttributes);
connect(_opcNode, &QOpcUaNode::attributeUpdated, this, &MyOPC::handleAttributes);

_opcNode->readAttributes(QOpcUa::NodeAttribute::Value);
```

Is it correct this approach? Should the manufacturer have told me also the namespace `ns=4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it correct this approach? Should the manufacturer have told me also the namespace ns=4?

That sounds correct to me. If something isn't working, I would double-check with them that both the namespace and the identifier are correct.

If you need a user-facing tool to help you navigate through UA while developing, I'd recommend using [UAExpert](https://www.unified-automation.com/products/development-tools/uaexpert.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should know the NamespaceUri and then preferably find the respective NamespaceIndex from the NamespaceArray that the server provides. Often, you can trust that the NamespaceIndex is fixed, but not always, so this will play it safe for you.

You can read the NamespaceArray (under Server object) with [UaExpert](https://www.unified-automation.com/products/development-tools/uaexpert.html) or [Prosys OPC UA Browser](https://www.prosysopc.com/products/opc-ua-browser/) and find the NamespaceUri from there yourself, too.

Or if your library supports providing the NodeId as ExpandedNodeId, you could simply use the NamespaceUri in it instead. This would then look in the XML string representation something like "nsu=urn:the_namespace_uri;s=MT_MAX_SETUP".